# Disprove that $f(n)=O(g(n)) \Rightarrow g(n)=O(f(n))$?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

I know that $f(n)=O(g(n)) \Rightarrow g(n)=O(f(n))$ can be disproved by simply showing a counterexample, such as $n = O(n^2)$ but $n^2 \neq O(n)$? Howeer, for no particular reason(except for my interest), I would like to know how to disprove this conjecture in the general case - like not just by a simple counterexample but using the definitions of big-O. Can you help?

Comment: There are some cases where $f=O(g)$ and $g=O(f).$ The way we disprove theorems like this is merely by conterexamples. You could, however, show that for every $f$ there is a $g$ such that $f=O(g)$ but $g\neq O(f).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for the input :) "The way we disprove theorems like this is merely by conterexamples." but disproving using the definition of $O$ for the general case must be possible - exactly as you mentioned in your comment. I would like to see such a disprove of this conjecture.

Comment: But other definitions might now have counter-examples for every $f.$ The counter-example also will use the definition of $O(\cdot).$

Comment: If you mean "not" in "But other definitions might now have counter-examples for every" - I finally get your points, thank you. But how would you show "You could, however, show that for every f there is a g such that f=O(g) but g≠O(f)"?